# Single mysql Query: To make NULL value of tables & there column's in database

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this possible with single query we can make all Columns and rows NULL or Zero(0) as its value ?

I have tried but failed to do with 2 3 tables in a Database; to make them NULL.

Comment: 's this possible with single query we can make all Columns and rows NULL or Zero(0) ' - No 1 update per table. You could write some code to interrogate information_schema,columns and generate sql for submission via dynamic sql. but that's going to be messy if you have foreign keys.(same applies to truncate)

Comment: Why do you want to store nothing but NULL values? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @jarlh  thanks alot. I'm just asking that is there's any possibility to make all tables of Database **Empty/NULL** with _single query_ .?

Comment: The answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update multiple tables in mysql you can use this:

```
UPDATE table1 , table2 SET table1.column = 0 , table2.column =0
```

If you don't know the fields you can generate an query to get all the sub-queries that you need

```
SELECT CONCAT("UPDATE `", TABLE_SCHEMA,"`.`", TABLE_NAME, "` SET `",COLUMN_NAME,"` = 0 ") AS MySQLCMD FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "you_db_name_here"
```

now you have all the queries to 0 all the columns in all the tables in database, so now what you can use PREPARE EXECUTE

```
SET @query :="";
SELECT @query := CONCAT("UPDATE `", TABLE_SCHEMA,"`.`", TABLE_NAME, "` SET `",COLUMN_NAME,"` = 0 ") AS MySQLCMD FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "you_db_name_here";
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

This will not work if you have primary keys, we need to skip them and the final result will look like this

```
SET @query :="";
SELECT @query := CONCAT("UPDATE `", C.TABLE_SCHEMA,"`.`", C.TABLE_NAME, "` SET `",C.COLUMN_NAME,"` = '' ") AS MySQLCMD from information_Schema.Columns C LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE U ON C.COLUMN_NAME = U.COLUMN_NAME WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = "you_db_name_here" AND U.CONSTRAINT_NAME is NULL;
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want or not.  I don't understand why you would want to set column values in existing rows to all `NULL` or `0`.  Wouldn't it be better just to empty the table, so there are no rows?  Then you can add new rows that you want.

To empty a table efficiently, use `truncate`:

```
truncate table t;
```

If you want to set all columns in a table to value, just use an `update` and list all the columns:

```
update t
    set col1 = null,
        col2 = null,
        . . .;
```

However, I don't see why this would be useful.

Comment: I can't understand it either but I think you've nailed the response.

Comment: thanks alot. I'm ok with truncate also. But just asking that is there's any possibility to make all tables of Database  **Empty/NULL**  with  _single query_ .?

Comment: @angel.bonev thanks alot..  But here now i have to write a huge query with there column names with respect to there table names. As i'm having huge big Database.

Comment: @angel.bonev you should provide your own answer rather than commenting in this one.

Comment: @angel.bonev   After executing your queries I'm getting bunch of Update queries.  Here they are:  ** `MySQLCMD` ** 
`UPDATE testing.tab1 SET id = 0;`
`UPDATE testing.tab1 SET name = 0;`
`UPDATE testing.tab1 SET email = 0;`
`UPDATE testing.tab1 SET phone = 0;`
`UPDATE testing.tab2 SET id = 0;`
`UPDATE testing.tab2 SET name = 0;`
`UPDATE testing.tab2 SET email = 0;`
`UPDATE testing.tab2 SET phone = 0; `

Comment: @apparently_in2_geeks you can see my answer below, let's comment there

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE ', TABLE_SCHEMA,'.', TABLE_NAME, ' SET ',COLUMN_NAME,' = 0;') AS MySQLCMD FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASE_NAME' ";

$result=$conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows> 0){
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $exe=$conn->query($row['MySQLCMD']);
}
```

}

Here's the Answer for what i need. Thanks alot for all your precious suggestions. And special thanks to :   [angel.bonev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3768239/angel-bonev)